# Front end form with images and media_handle_upload logic?

Tags: uploads, media

I'm building a front-end form with image submissions.
The form creates then a new post:

```
...process post...
$application_id = wp_insert_post($application);
```

I then use `media_handle_upload` to upload image and attach them to the post:

```
...process file...
$file_id = media_handle_upload("upload_file", $application_id);
```

It works fine — my issue is that everything happens on submit, so the files is uploading only after the user clicks the submit button.

Is there a way to upload the images straight when the user adds them to the input field? What happens if the user then abandons the form — how would I delete the images then?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't like the way it works now?  I makes sense to NOT upload the media files until the post has been submitted because then you're not stuck with the extra issue of deleting the images if the user aborts.

Comment: @TonyDjukic the reason is that it's additional wait if images are uploaded on submit and most services upload immediately so that's what users are used to

Answer (score 0):

try below the code front end form with media handle upload in Wordpress.

```
<form id="post-submission-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" accept="image/*" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Post">
</form>
<div id="image-preview"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#upload_file').change(function() {
        var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // WordPress AJAX URL
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#image-preview').html('<img src="' + response + '" />');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#post-submission-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                // Handle post submission response here
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


funcitons.php


add_action('wp_ajax_upload_image', 'upload_image_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_image', 'upload_image_callback');

function upload_image_callback() {
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['file'];
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploaded_file, $upload_overrides);

    if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])) {
        echo $movefile['url'];
    } else {
        echo 'Error uploading file.';
    }

    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My idea is to upload on change though and delete if form is not submitted.